# Is there a function for adding a Directory to an zip file?

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to add a directory with stuff in it to a zip archive. The zip archive is already existing.
I did not find any library with such an function. Do you know a library that has such a function?

Comment: you mean is there a way to add to a .zip file without unzipping, adding and re-zipping again?

Comment: did you try standard module `zipfile`? If you want add to existing `.zip` then you may try to open in `append mode` (`"a"`). If you want to add all files from directory then you have to use `os.listdir(directory)` with `for`-loop  to add every file separatelly. If you want to have subfolder inside `zip` then you can use `arcname="folder/filename"` in `write()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard module [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

---

To add to existing `.zip` you can open in `append more` (`"a"`)

```
zipfile.ZipFile('output.zip', 'a')
```

---

To add all files from directory you need `os.listdir(directory)` and `for`-loop to add every file separatelly.

And if you have subfolders then it may need `os.walk(directory)` instead of `os.listdir(directory)`.

```py
    folder = 'test'

    with zipfile.ZipFile('output.zip', 'a') as myzip:

        for filename in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):

            fullpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)

            myzip.write(fullpath) #, arcname=filename)
```

If you want to create `folder` inside `.zip` then you have to use name `folder/filename` as `name` (you can't go to `folder` usig `os.chdir()` and add `filename`) or you can create it using `arcname="folder/filename"`.

For example you can use current time to create new folder in `zip`.

```py
    src_folder = 'test'
    
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    dst_folder = date.strftime('%H-%m-%S')   # one folder 
    #dst_folder = date.strftime('%H/%m/%S')  # many folders separated by `/`

    with zipfile.ZipFile('output.zip', 'a') as myzip:

        for filename in sorted(os.listdir(src_folder)):

            src_fullpath = os.path.join(src_folder, filename)
            dst_fullpath = os.path.join(dst_folder, filename)

            myzip.write(src_fullpath, arcname=dst_fullpath)
```

---

**BTW:**

Code to check what was created in zip file

```py
    with zipfile.ZipFile('output.zip', 'r') as myzip:
        for item in myzip.filelist:
            print(item.filename)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. I feel somehow stupid. I did not think of "a" as mode.